# Send variabiles ajax

Tags: php, ajax

1.php

```
...
<script src="/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = $a
var b = $b
var c = $c

apclick = function() {
    $.ajax({        
            url: 'a1.php',
            data: { a: a, b: b, c: c },
            datatype: json,
            success: function(results) {
                if (results.msg == 'success') {
                    alert(a)
                    alert(b)
                    alert(c)
                } else {
                    alert(results.msg)
                }
            },
            error: function(results) {
                alert("Data returned: " + results.msg )
            }
    });

    setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 3000)                               
    return false;              
}

</script>

.....
<strong><br><a href="#" onclick="apclick();return false;">Afiseaza </a></strong>
```

a1.php

```
<?php

$return = array();
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c']

if ($a == "hello") {
    $return['msg'] = 'success';
    $return['a'] = "Buna";
};

if ($b == "say") {
    $return['msg'] = 'success';
    $return['a'] = "Spune";
};

if ($c == "man") {
    $return['msg'] = 'success';
    $return['a'] = "Om";
};

header("Content-type: application/json");

echo json_encode($a);
echo json_encode($b);
echo json_encode($c);

?>
```

Questions is:
How send a,b,c to a1.php and receive a,b,c in 1.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided had several syntax errors, you should have fixed them before posting it.

Anyway, here is the working code for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = "hello";
    var b = "say";
    var c = "man";
    var res;
    apclick = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'a1.php',
            data: { a: a, b: b, c: c },
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(results) {
                res = results;
                if (results.msg == 'success') {
                    alert(results.a)
                    alert(results.a)
                    alert(results.a)
                }
                else {
                    alert(results.msg)
                }
            },
            error: function(results) {
                alert("Data returned: " + results.msg );
            }
        });

        setTimeout("location.reload(true);",30000);
        return false;
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>

<strong>
    <br>
    <a href="#" onclick="apclick();return false;">Afiseaza </a>
</strong>
```

And the a1.php:

```
<?php

$return = array();
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

if ($a == "hello") {
    $return['msg'] = 'success';
    $return['a'] = "Buna";
};

if ($b == "say") {
    $return['msg'] = 'success';
    $return['a'] = "Spune";
};

if ($c == "man") {
    $return['msg'] = 'success';
    $return['a'] = "Om";
};

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

Comment: What is the role of variable res?

Comment: i received that message Data returned: undefined

Comment: Ignore the variable "res". I added to check the code, should have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: { 'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c' },
type: 'POST'
```

Try that (with the quotes on the data and type set to POST.)

Comment: Dont' work. Is correct data: { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' },
type: 'POST'

Answer (score 0):

thumbs up for rsmoorthy but I woudln't use $_REQUEST

decide your request method and set the type as Gazler suggested accordingly.

Comment: PS: $_REQUEST might cause security issues